# Aligning zeros in two Y Axis of DataVisualization.Charting.Chart

Tags: vb.net, charts, axis, data-visualization

I have two series in a DataVisualization.Charting.Chart and two AxisY (AxisY1, and AxisY2). I was able to draw both series on a chart but the zeros for the left axis and right axis are not aligned. How can I align the zeros for the two axis?

```
NetChart.Series.Clear()
NetChart.Series.Add("Net")
NetChart.Series.Add("Net Cum.")
NetChart.Series(0).Points.Clear()
NetChart.Series(1).Points.Clear()

Dim netSaleDT As DataTable = SomeDataTable
netSaleDT.Columns.Add("CumulativeNet", GetType(Decimal))
Dim index As Integer = 0
Dim cumulSum As Decimal = 0
For Each drow As DataRow In netSaleDT.Rows
     cumulSum += Convert.ToDecimal(drow("Net"))
     drow("CumulativeNet") = cumulSum
     NetChart.Series(0).Points.AddXY(drow("myMonth"), Convert.ToDecimal(drow("Net")))
     NetChart.Series(1).Points.AddXY(drow("myMonth"), Convert.ToDecimal(drow("CumulativeNet")))
     NetChart.Series(0).Points(index).AxisLabel = drow("myMonth")
     index += 1
Next

NetChart.Series(0).YAxisType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.AxisType.Primary
NetChart.Series(1).YAxisType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.AxisType.Secondary
NetChart.Series(1).ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line
NetChart.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Interval = 2
NetChart.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "C"
NetChart.ChartAreas(0).AxisY2.LabelStyle.Format = "C"

NetChart.Series(1).BorderWidth = 2
NetChart.Series(1).Color = Color.Blue
NetChart.ChartAreas(0).AxisY2.Enabled = DataVisualization.Charting.AxisEnabled.True
NetChart.ChartAreas(0).AxisY2.LabelStyle.Enabled = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the axis properties set to auto?

If they are you need to manually set each axis programatically.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axis.minimum%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

When I set the min/max I usually do something like this:

```
        Dim myChart As Excel.ChartObject = CType(xlCharts.Item(y), ChartObject)
        Dim chartPage As Excel.Chart = myChart.Chart
        chartPage.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlCategory).minimumscale = minimum
        chartPage.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlCategory).maximumscale = maximum
```

This changes the x axis scale, to change the Y scale:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chartarea.axisy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

and to change the secondary y scale:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chartarea.axisy2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Hope this helps

*Edit

Well i was trying to not give you the whole answer

But I suppose:

```
    Dim myChart As Excel.ChartObject = CType(QoE.xLSheet1.ChartObjects(0), ChartObject)
    Dim chartPage As Excel.Chart = myChart.Chart
    chartPage.Axes(Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary).minimumscale = 0
    chartPage.Axes(Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlSecondary).minimumscale = 0
```

Set the chart object to whatever chart you are trying to change, then set both the primary and secondary y axis to 0

Comment: I could not translate your response from Excel which is what you provided for to Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart which is what I'm looking for.

Comment: can you set NetChart.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.MinimumScale = 0
NetChart.ChartAreas(0).AxisY2.MinimumScale = 0 or instead of MinimumScale it just might be minimum

Comment: Well, I guess we made some progress. NetChart.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.        .Minimum = 0 and for AxisY2 aligns the two zeros on Y Axis but the problem is, negative values are not being shown at all. So the graph is missing any data points that otherwise would be shown as negative values.

Comment: Then set the minimum to -5 or whatever you want the minimum to be. It doesnt have to be 0

Comment: That wouldn't help. Because then my graph starts at -5. There won't be any zero axis and if there is zero axis there is no guarantee that the two zero axis (for Y and Y2) would align.

Comment: Just set the minimum to the lowest number in the dataset. NetChart.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Minimum = minimum_Number ... Find the minimum number programatically, and set it to that. It doesnt have to be 0 or -5, the number can be literally anything. To get the numbers to align, set the intervals to the same amount. If the graphs start at the same number and have the same interval, they will be the same throughout the entire graph. NetChart.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Interval = 1 ... Again it doesnt have to be 1, just like the minimum, it can be done programatically and can literally be any number